# How to indicate dynamic additions support in json schema?

Tags: jsonschema

Just started with jsonschema. I want to describe a collection of objects for a property where the key may not be known a priori.

Here is my starting point:

```json
                "tx_properties": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "anyOf": [
                        {
                            "required": [
                                "original_msg"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "original_msg": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I want to be able to validate the additions of more properties for `tx_properties` that may have different types but are not known at schema definition time.

For example I might have, in json:

```json
"tx_properties": {
    "original_msg": "foo",
    "something_else": "bar",
    "or_something_numeric": 172,
    "or_even_deeper_things": {
        "fungible": false,
    }
}
```

As a n00b I'm a bit stuck on how to accomplish this. The use of `anyOne` is what I thought I needed at least in the final solution.

Comment: By default you can add anything to an object if, only when you specify `additionalProperties: false` this is not true. Maybe I'm misunderstanding

Comment: @Evert are you saying that with the schema I've described at the top of the message, if I validate against the data example I've also shown... it will validate OK?

Comment: you mean you havent tried it?

Comment: @Evert Not yet... I need to get the test data generator going but by EOD I should

Comment: @Evert - Works, thanks for the insight and `Ether` for expanding and including the link.

Comment: I'd really recommend putting some minimal effort in before you ask others for help!

Comment: That is very presumptive. As I noted I am a newbie to the whole JSON schema thing and spent many hours searching before entering the question. Not my first rodeo.

Comment: I meant I would suggest you run some code. You asked about something that is default behavior and your sample would have run without error. It's very low effort to test this vs. asking the community. Even after I gave you the answer you asked me if it would work instead of validating it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Evert said, `"additionalProperties": false` can be used to indicate that no other properties other than those listed in `properties` keywords (and `patternProperties`) are permitted. If `additionalProperties` is omitted, the behaviour is as if the schema said `"additionalProperties": true` (that is, additional properties are permitted).

Also note that the value at `additionalProperties` doesn't have to be a boolean: it can be a subschema itself, to allow you to conditionally allow for additional properties depending on their value(s).

Reference: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#additional-properties